# Integrate $\int_{-1}^1 \frac x{e^x+x+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

How to approach this integral?I tried to add subtract $e^{x}+1$. But I didn't get too far.

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{x}{e^{x}+x+1}dx$$

Answer (score 5):

The hint:

Use $$\frac{x}{e^x+x+1}=1-\frac{e^x+1}{e^x+x+1}.$$

Comment: Thank you, I did it :)

Comment: @Vali RO You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$$\begin{align}\int_{-1}^1\frac{x}{e^x+1+x}\mathrm dx&=\int_{-1}^1\frac{x+e^x+1-e^x-1}{e^x+1+x}\mathrm dx\\&=\int_{-1}^1\left(1-\frac{1+e^x}{1+x+e^x}\right)\mathrm dx\end{align}$$

Can you see how the numerator and denominator relate to each other in the new fractional term? How do you integrate such terms?

Comment: I take u=e^x+x so u'=e^x+1 so the second integral is ln|u+1|

Comment: Thank you, I did it :)

Comment: @ValiRO yes exactly :)